# Xcode Swift Large tuple fills all free disk space and throws an error

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-management, tuples, out-of-memory

I created a tuple in my application and while it was small the project compiled quickly. But the size of the tuple increased to three thousand lines and when building Xcode, it began to eat up all the free disk space and give an error -  an error occurred...
I do not understand what's the matter.

The disk has 25 gigabytes free and they all fill up. If i free up to 30 gigabytes, then the project is compiled, but you have to wait 3-4 minutes !!!

Is my tuple too large or is this an Xcode issue? Can I store data differently?

```
let cameras: [(String, Double, Double, String)] = [
    ("Cam1",    55.42002,     -110.80779,      "http://sitess.com/1.jpg"),
    ("Cam2",    55.42002,    -110.80779,    "http://sitess.com/2.jpg")
]
```

Comment: You have not at all shown that the tuples are the cause of the memory usage. But even if not, they are utterly silly in this context. Use a struct!

Comment: Also do not construct a huge array as a literal. Build it at runtime, perhaps from a plist.

Comment: Without more code it's impossible to know what is happening. How the class where this is defined is initialized and used? How are you saving this data to disk?

Comment: @zeytin, yes. Same problem in playground where I just do print (cameras)

Comment: @PaulLochte make a struct as matt said at the comments

Comment: @zeytin did not help)